# PowerPC version of Go

Tags: go, version, powerpc

I just got access to a powerful Minski IBM machine (Linux) and intend on running some go scripts on it. I have gone through a lot of the versions of golang and tried installing and using them on the machine but none of them seem to work. Is there some special version of GO that I need that is specially designed to work on this powerful computer.

I have now tried installing about 4 or 5 different versions but still keep getting:

```
The program 'go' is currently not installed. To run 'go' please ask your administrator to install the package 'golang-go'
```

I was told that there is no need for an administrator to do a system wide install and to just install golang on my machine.

I have been using this step-by-step to install GO on this machine:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-go-1-6-on-ubuntu-14-04

I do not have root access on this machine, just FYI

**EDIT:**
Problem solved

Had to use:

```
curl -O storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.3.linux-ppc64le.tar.gz
```

Comment: Sounds like you're not running this line: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`.  Go has to be in your path in order for the `go` command to mean anything to the OS.

Comment: I'm actually trying to not install it in `/usr/local` therefore I am trying to do the following two lines that appear in the step-by-step guide:
`export GOROOT=$HOME/go`,
`export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin`

Comment: Don't go by random, possibly out of date blog posts, just check the official documentation: https://golang.org/doc/install. If you've installed it and the `go` binary isn't found, it just means you haven't properly updated your PATH.

Comment: Where did you install Go at?  Is it actually _installed_ at `$HOME/go`?

Comment: Reinstalled and now I get 
`-bash: /home/cherukr2/go/bin/go: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

I am pretty sure this error has to do with this being the wrong version for the Minski machine. Do you know what version I should be using by any chance?

Comment: @VarKarCher: Try https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.3.linux-ppc64le.tar.gz

Comment: If you meant you have a "Minksy" machine, which IIRC has a Power8 cpu, installing the amd64 architecture is not going to work. Download the appropriate ppc version, or follow the directions for building from source: https://golang.org/doc/install/source

Comment: @JimB: Go officially supports the Linux OS and the ppc64le architecture: System requirements https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: @peterSO, it worked. That was what I was looking for. Thank You

Comment: Go v1.18.5 fails to compile on a Power4 Big Endian system with an `Illegal Instruction` error at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Go Downloads](https://golang.org/dl/)

PowerPC architecture: ppc64le (64-bit PowerPC little-endian). For example, for Go 1.8.3,

go1.8.3.linux-ppc64le.tar.gz: https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.3.linux-ppc64le.tar.gz